# Using Recursion to get combinations of Numbers in C# that equal the same sum

Tags: c#, recursion

UPDATE:  Okay I've revamped this question due to some negative people that merely want to complain rather than attempt to provide some sort of constructive help.

I know variations of this question have been asked, but I'm fairly certain mine is different.

I'm trying to do something similar to the tic tac toe Magic Box, but with a variation.

Traditionally, the Magic TicTacToe box refers to the numbers 1-9 and you're asked to arrange them in the tictactoe box in such a way that every iteration of the sets of 3 equal the same.  In that sense, each run of 3 numbers would have to equal 15.  With every possible direction, there's 8 sequences to test. The important part of the calculation is that the total sum of 1-9 is 45 and that divided by 3 is what tells you each run of 3 should equal 15.

Now, as I understand it, there's a form of recursion that would have to take place to run through the combinations of numbers, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I'd like to be able to put a number (divisible by 3 and 9) in for an input and have it not only determine the unique (non-recurring) numbers it takes to get to that total, but how those numbers should be used.

Example:
I know I can simply divide a number by 9 to determine the median, which in this case already gives me one letter, which would be E in this case. I know I can simply run a couple for loops to get the remaining numbers. What I'm not sure how to do is figure out the recursion process to determine the correct assignment of each number.

Here's the example of the letter assignment:

```
G  |  F  |  A
H  |  E  |  B
I  |  D  |  C
```

You'd need the following combinations:

```
A+B+C
F+E+D
G+H+I
A+E+I
G+E+C
G+F+A
H+E+B
I+D+C
```

Now, what I'm not sure of, and the effect it could have, is the frequency in which each number is used. I know each of the above sequences would need to equal the number input divided by 3 would in this case would be 30, but I'm not sure what important facts can be used to create the proper nested for loops and/or if statements that sort through the list or array of numbers created and properly assign them based on their relevance.

Considering E is used 4 times (which is why it's the center), A,C,I, and G are used 3 times, and H,B,D, and F are used 2 times.

So, for clarification, I would like all of this to output what A,B,C, etc. should be equal to given the restrictions.

Thanks for any help.
As an additional request, although not required, but extremely appreciated - if you do provide an answer, explaining some of the important portions of the recursions, functions used and how it achieves my desired outcome would be great.

I think I've made my question clear at this point.  In regards to someone's comment, yes I'm asking for the code, because I one am not proficient enough to figure out the complex use of recursion it would take to constantly check the needed constraints required, and two, no other questions really get into the kind of detail I feel I'm trying to go to.  Most just what a normal statistical use of Combinations and Permutations, but it doesn't seem there's as many restrictions on the results, and/or their end goal is different.

For the sake of making some things clear, here's another edit:

Below is what I have to first generate the list of all the numbers that will be used.

```
        int A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I;
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a number that's all 9 spots added together.");
        Console.WriteLine("Make sure the number is divisble by 3 and 9.");
        int myNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int sums = myNumber / 3;
        E = myNumber / 9;
        if (E%1 != 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a value divisible by 3 and 9");
            Console.WriteLine("Try again.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        else
        {
            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            int lowest = E - 4;
            for (int x = lowest;x < E; x++)
            {

                list.Add(x);
            }
            int highest = E + 4;
            for (int y=E;y<highest;y++)
            {
                list.Add(y+1);
            }

            //Testing output

            foreach (int i in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
```

I made this to first see if I could establish the numbers that would be used, then go into finding all the variations of the numbers that would make all the lines equal the same.  For example:  if they entered 45, all directions would have to equal 15; if they entered 90, all directions would have to equal 30, etc.

Comment: You are asking for multiple things. For instance, to determine the number series, just divide the input by 9. That gives you your middle point in your 9 digit series. Now just take all the numbers from 4 less than your middle to 4 more than your middle point, and you have your 9 number series to use.

Comment: Your other part then uses those series of 9 numbers to determine the magic square arrangement.

Comment: Your "question" appears to be "please write me some code that does X". Can you formulate an actual question that you want an answer to? Then put it in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Knock yourself out.

```
Func<IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<int[]>> permutate = null;
permutate = ns =>
{
    if (!ns.Skip(1).Any())
    {
        return new [] { ns.ToArray() };
    }
    else
    {
        return
            from n in ns
            from ns2 in permutate(ns.Except(new [] { n }))
            select new [] { n }.Concat(ns2).ToArray();
    }
};

var results =
    permutate(Enumerable.Range(1, 9))
        .Where(ns => Enumerable.Range(0, 3).All(n => ns[n * 3] + ns[n * 3 + 1] + ns[n * 3 + 2] == 15))
        .Where(ns => Enumerable.Range(0, 3).All(n => ns[n] + ns[3 + n] + ns[6 + n] == 15))
        .Where(ns => Enumerable.Range(0, 3).All(n => ns[0] + ns[4] + ns[8] == 15))
        .Where(ns => Enumerable.Range(0, 3).All(n => ns[2] + ns[4] + ns[6] == 15));
```

This gives:

```
2, 7, 6
9, 5, 1
4, 3, 8

2, 9, 4
7, 5, 3
6, 1, 8

4, 3, 8
9, 5, 1
2, 7, 6

4, 9, 2
3, 5, 7
8, 1, 6

6, 1, 8
7, 5, 3
2, 9, 4

6, 7, 2
1, 5, 9
8, 3, 4

8, 1, 6
3, 5, 7
4, 9, 2

8, 3, 4
1, 5, 9
6, 7, 2
```

Comment: This a great example.  I really appreciate it.  What I would be curious to know though, is what would I need to adjust or change to be able to do this with any set of numbers.  As given in my example. If I just had one input of 90 which would give a list of numbers: 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14  I asked because I created some code that figures out what the list of numbers are, I'm wondering how I could just adjust what you made there by changing the range to a List<int> of numbers, if that's even possible?

Comment: Additionally, how could I cycle through the results to output them in the fashion you've displayed them here?  I've tried to view the results the Locals view during Debug, but a timeout error pops up.  I tried to create a foreach statement that cycled through the results, but maybe I'm not understanding how the results are being stored as the variations of numbers are created.

Comment: @TekGiant - I don't know what you mean by "If I just had one input of 90 which would give a list of numbers: 6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14"?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine, results.Select(x => String.Join(Environment.NewLine, new [] { String.Join(", ", x.Take(3)), String.Join(", ", x.Skip(3).Take(3)), String.Join(", ", x.Skip(6).Take(3)), }))));`

Comment: I probably could have been more clear.  What I mean is, for example.  1 through 9, each added together, creates a sum of 45.  45/9 giving you the median of 5.  This is how I was originally going to approach the problem on my own. Because the median would always be the center number, therein giving me 1 out of the 9 numbers I need to figure out.  So, what my goal was, is to be able to put in 1 number that's both divisible by 3 and 9 (i.e. 45, 90, 108) things like that and then get the possible results from the 9 numbers that sum together equal the number input by the user. I made an edit.

Comment: @TekGiant - I'm still not with you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85365/discussion-between-tekgiant-and-enigmativity).

Answer (score 0):

I understand what @tekGiant is asking but I do not know how to answer it yet...

```
G  |  F  |  A
H  |  E  |  B
I  |  D  |  C
```

You'd need the following combinations:

```
A+B+C=X
F+E+D=X
G+H+I=X
A+E+I=X
G+E+C=X
G+F+A=X
H+E+B=X
I+D+C=X
```

Where X is the initial number that you designate to be the one that each of the different combinations add up to.